# How to set up OpenWrt traffic rule for port forwarding IPv6 server on my LAN?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, ipv6, openwrt

I would like to allow inbound IPv6 traffic on ports 80/443 for a globally routable web server on my home network.  What's the best way to do this with OpenWrt, which by default blocks incoming IPv6 traffic (as a good firewall should)?

My ISP (Comcast) assigns me a /60 prefix for delegation via DHCPv6.  It sometimes changes.  The web server (Ubuntu) gets a global IPv6 address via SLAAC from the OpenWrt router.

As per https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/firewall#port_accept_for_ipv6 you can set up a traffic rule to allow this kind of traffic:

> To open port 80 so that a local webserver at 2001:db8:42::1337 can be
>   reached from the Internet:
>
> ```
> config rule
>         option src       wan
>         option proto     tcp
>         option dest      lan
>         option dest_ip   2001:db8:42::1337
>         option dest_port 80
>         option family    ipv6
>         option target    ACCEPT
> ```

Easy enough, except.... the destination IP is hard-coded!

**How might one set up this type of rule when the destination IP is potentially changing?** (due to changes in the delegated prefix from my ISP).  Presumably, it has to be updated periodically....  Has anyone attempted this and if so, what works well / doesn't work well?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and dead end as you. I wrote a quick and dirty script to automate the firewall changes for me.

```
#!/bin/sh

# CONFIGURABLE PARAMETER: PREFIX
# the prefix is the prefix of all the firewall rules that should be changed
PREFIX=DynamicIPv6
PREFIX_LEN=${#PREFIX}

# get current IPv6 prefix from WAN
. /lib/functions/network.sh
network_get_prefix6 prefix6 wan6
prefix6=$(echo $prefix6 | cut -d/ -f1)
prefix_len=$(expr ${#prefix6} - 1)
prefix6=${prefix6:0:$prefix_len}

changed=0
index=0
name=$(uci get firewall.@rule[$index].name 2> /dev/null)
while [ "$name" != "" ]; do
    subname=${name:0:$PREFIX_LEN}

    # if the prefix matches, determine whether to change the firewall rules
    if [ "$subname" == "$PREFIX" ]; then
            dest_ip=$(uci get firewall.@rule[$index].dest_ip 2> /dev/null)
            dest_network=${dest_ip:0:$prefix_len}
            host_addr=$(echo $dest_ip | awk -F: 'BEGIN { OFS=":"; } { print $5,$6,$7,$8 }')

            # if the firewall rule and prefix mismatch, update the firewall
            if [ "$dest_network" != "$prefix6" ]; then
                    changed=1
                    new_ip="${prefix6}${host_addr}"
                    uci set firewall.@rule[$index].dest_ip=$new_ip
                    uci commit firewall
            fi
    fi

    # advance to the next firewall rule
    index=$(expr $index + 1)
    name=$(uci get firewall.@rule[$index].name 2> /dev/null)
done

# if changes were detected, then reload the firewall
if [ $changed -eq 1 ]; then
    /etc/init.d/firewall reload 2> /dev/null
fi
```

To use the script:

1. Create your firewall rules using the `PREFIX` in the script.
2. Schedule the script to run using cron.

**Known Issue:** The script is limited to full IPv6 addresses and can't use the :: short hand. (e.g., 2600:dead:beef:cafe:0:0:0:1 instead of 2600:dead:beef:cafe::1).

The script is far from perfect, so be kind. I offer the script in hopes you will find it useful. :)

Comment: For this answer to be useful, you should at least try and explain what the script does. `Read it yourself` answers are not very useful, on a Q&A site, and they are surely frowned up on StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Dynamic Prefix Forwarding](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/fw3_configurations/fw3_ipv6_examples#dynamic_prefix_forwarding) as it has a trick where you can use negative numbers for the prefix.

> Configure a [static DHCPv6 lease](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp_configuration#static_leases) and add a forwarding rule:
>
> ```
> uci add firewall rule
> uci set firewall.@rule[-1].name="Forward-IPv6"
> uci set firewall.@rule[-1].src="wan"
> uci set firewall.@rule[-1].dest="lan"
> uci set firewall.@rule[-1].dest_ip="::123/-64"
> uci set firewall.@rule[-1].family="ipv6"
> uci set firewall.@rule[-1].proto="tcpudp"
> uci set firewall.@rule[-1].target="ACCEPT"
> uci commit firewall
> /etc/init.d/firewall restart
> ```